# Como fazer para um arquivo batch executar uma Aplicação Console passando parâmetro?

Tags: c#, batch, console

Tenho uma Aplicação Console que o método `main` do *Program.cs* (onde inicia a aplicação) recebe um *input*.

Segue código abaixo:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{   
    var input = Console.ReadLine();

    ControleEstado.IniciaControle(input);

    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Preciso criar um arquivo *batch* que execute essa aplicação porém envie o parâmetro esperado na variável *input*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar o comando [**start**](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html) para executar o arquivo.

```
@echo off
start /b consoleApp.exe foo
```

E para receber os argumentos passados a aplicação faça:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    foreach (string arg in args) {
        string input = arg.Trim();
        switch (input) {
            case "foo":
                Console.WriteLine("Foo");
                break;
            case "bar":
                Console.WriteLine("Bar");
                break;
            case "baz":
                Console.WriteLine("Baz");
                break;
            default:
                Console.WriteLine(input);
                break;
            }
        }
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Funcionou! Obrigado!!!